# How can we create dynamic json object in powershell

Tags: json, powershell

I am creating powershell script which generation json file where i want to create json object runtime based on mentioned name in $env variable and put some value inside it as json.

```
$env="prd,test,dev,..,...." # there are total 15 env & $env has 1 and more env.
```

Desire JSON :

```
{
 
   "prd" : {
         "Sid": "xxxxxx" }
   "test" : {
         "Sid": "xxx" }

   "So on" : {}
}
```

Trying to write script:

```
$env="prd,test,..,...,.."

$env=$env - split ","
For ( $i = 0 $i -le ($env.length -1) ;$i+=1){

    $env[$i] = New-object System.Collection.ArrayList

    $env[$i].add("anydata10")

}
```

But this approach not working well since $env variable has any 1 or more env value.

In the powershell, can we create dynamic json object at runtime and any other approch to archive it ?

Comment: How does `prd` become `prodsid1`? Where did the `o` come from? :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen No, value can be anything which get it from somewhere.

Comment: Why are you overwriting `$env`? There's no tax on variables. For the result you probably want to start with a new hash table entirely (`$result = @{}`) and build that up before feeding it to `ConvertTo-Json`. Nested hash tables work fine too: `$result = @{}; $result.Add("prd", @{Sid="xxxxx"}); $result | ConvertTo-Json`.

Answer (score 3):

For the root-level object (`{"prd":{...}, "test":{...}}`), I'd suggest an ordered dictionary, then create a custom object with the `Sid` property for each property:

```
# prepare env keys
$environments = "prd,test,dev,stg,qa" -split ","

# create ordered dictionary
$jsonObject = [ordered]@{}

foreach($envName in $environments){
    # create 1 property, the value of which will be an object with a `Sid` property
    $jsonObject[$envName] = [pscustomobject]@{
        # resolve the correct `Sid` value from somewhere
        Sid = Get-SidForEnv $envName
    }
}

# convert the whole thing to json
$jsonObject |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

Based on your comments about getting the correct sid value "from somewhere", I assume you already have a function that translates `prd` to `prodsid1` and so forth, so simply replace `Get-SidForEnv` with whatever function that is :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. You can access environment variables using `$env`. So, if you have those values `prd,test,...` in some environment variable and you want to generate new environment variables based on those, you can do it like this:

```
#  $env:foo contains 'prd,test'
$env:foo -split ',' | % {
  New-Item -Path Env: -Name $_ -Value (@("anydata10") | ConvertTo-Json)  
}
```